# Generic Limits Type

Tags: generics, max, d, html, min

Has anyone cooked up a generic D struct that groups together min
and max values of a type and default-initializes them in the
correct way?

Something like

```
 alias Pair(T) = Tuple!(T, T);

 struct Limits(T)
 {
     /* TODO: Fix purity of this by fixing Bytes.value() */
     auto init() @trusted /* pure */ nothrow { return tuple(T.max, T.min); }
     alias _minmax this;
     Pair!T _minmax;
 }
 auto limits(T)() { return Limits!T(); }
 unittest {
     Limits!int x;
     dln(x);
 }
```

I want min and max to default initialize to T.max, T.min so they
are prepared for `x = min/max(x, ...)` logic. But the code
above doesn't work because the init() function isn't called and I
don't know why. And I can't use default member initialization
because I want `Limits` to work also with types such as `SysTime`
when min and max are only know at run-time.

I'm aware of `std.datetime.span` but it isn't generic.

Ideas anyone?

See also: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/dwuiknzqzmjkefnwmnio@forum.dlang.org#post-dwuiknzqzmjkefnwmnio:40forum.dlang.org

**Update**:

I just read that I should be using `std.datetime.Interval` when `T` is a `SysTime`. This simplifies things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `init` function isn't called because you never call it! D *never* does default construction beyond copying the initializers over. The way to do this kind of thing is to `@disable this();`,  making the use of `Limits!int x;` a compile error, forcing the user to call a factory function or constructor with an argument to initialize it.

```
struct S {
     @disable this(); // disable S s; declars
     this(int min, int max) { ... } // allow S s = S(0, 10);
}
```